# How to apply a Gabor filter to an image with hexagonal sampling?

Tags: python, image-processing, gabor-filter

I want to use a Gabor filter as an interpolation method after the conversion of a square-sampled image to an hexagonally-sampled image.

Can I use the normal Gabor filter implementation in an hexagonally-sampled image? Or should I modify the code? If yes, then what part of the Gabor function should I modify for an hexagonally-sampled image?

I've tried implementing the algorithm but I just can't get it right. 
Here's a code for Gabor filtering [taken from GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Libardo1/53b285029816009f94eabccb8038fd59).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# cv2.getGaborKernel(ksize, sigma, theta, lambda, gamma, psi, ktype)
# ksize - size of gabor filter (n, n)
# sigma - standard deviation of the gaussian function
# theta - orientation of the normal to the parallel stripes
# lambda - wavelength of the sunusoidal factor
# gamma - spatial aspect ratio
# psi - phase offset
# ktype - type and range of values that each pixel in the gabor kernel can hold

g_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((21, 21), 8.0, np.pi/4, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
filtered_img = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('filtered image', filtered_img)

h, w = g_kernel.shape[:2]
g_kernel = cv2.resize(g_kernel, (3*w, 3*h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow('gabor kernel (resized)', g_kernel)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Oh, Im sorry. I shouldve reviewes my question.  Thanks tho. . Hmm do you have any idea about my question sir?? Thanks.

Comment: I sincerely doubt it's going to be so easy.  You'll just need to roll your own.  All of these image processing libraries are doing matrix multiplication and slicing.  None of that translates to hex grids in a way that you could just "patch up."  Notably, that convolution operation is just doing some slicing and multiplying over squares.  Speaking of which, what is the shape of your filter?  Do you want it to be hexagonal or square?

Comment: @Scott i  have already found an implementation for Converting Square image to Hexagonal. I am stuck after that since the imsge need interpolation after the transformation so I want to apply hex-gabor to it and wavelet denoising. So is it ok to apply a square shaped filtee to a Hexagonally sampled image or not? Thank you I really appreciate your reply. Ive been looking everywhere but all I know is i should implement this on my own since there is no open library for hexagonal image processing.

Comment: What is the orientation of your hexagonal grid?  (i.e. do the hexagons' flat edges go horizonal or vertical?)

Comment: So, new questions come up: **(1)** How do you use a Gabor filter for interpolation? I have never heard of such a thing. Are you sure you need a Gabor filer? Maybe you confuse it with something else? **(2)** "I've tried implementing the algorithm", yet you post code you've copied from elsewhere. Why don't you show your attempts? It would be helpful to know how far you got, and see where the problem is. Also, it will help us see how you implemented the hexagonal sampling.

Comment: @Scott in my research I implemented a conversion which will yield "Fixed horizontal Lattice spacing" is that what you are asking??? I used conversion from square to hexagonal implemented by middleton in 2005.

Comment: @CrisLuengo here is the abstract of the previous research I found using Gabor filter as interpolation . Please correct me If im wrong "An interpolation model using Gabor Filter is demonstrated on 
hexagonally sampled data, which outperform classical B-splines 
and MOMS. Our method has optimal approximation theoretic 
performances, for a good quality image. The computational cost 
is considerably low when compared to similar processing in the 
rectangular domain..."

Comment: @CrisLuengo the title of this Research is "Gabor Functions for interpolation on Hexagonal lattice" by Veni.S

Comment: I found [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6738204) about interpolation using the Gabor filter. The abstract claims that they use the Gabor filter to determine edge direction. This is weird, as the Gabor filter is not really meant for that. I'm not judging their results, maybe this method really is good, but it likely would be faster, simpler and more accurate to use Gaussian derivatives to find the edge direction.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ill try your suggestion about gaussian derivatives and Ill read this paper. Thank you

Comment: I found the paper by Veni S., but couldn't make heads or tails from it. I don't know what they actually do. They apply a Gabor filter with a Hanning window to an image, and the image miraculously becomes sharper... that is not what a Gabor filter is supposed to do! The Gabor filter has a Gaussian window, I don't understand why it needs a second window. They don't discuss any details about sizes for this window either. I suggest you look for better papers to replicate in your project.

Comment: @CrisLuengo okay sir thanks. . Can I update you using your email??? Mine is frankeejigzz@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ordinary data structure for a hexagonal grid, you can probably apply a 2d filter to a hexagonal-pixel image, but you need to create a filter that is evaluated at the appropriate coordinates.  You see, a 2d filter is just a matrix of values generated by evaluating a function over xy coordinates in a grid.  So, a 5x5 Gabor filter matrix is just a Gabor function evaluated at the xy coordinates shown here:

[image]

Pixels are "equally spaced" so we can simply pick the distance between each point in the grid to be 1 in x and 1 in y, and we get the Gabor function evaluated at the *center* of each pixel.

However, hexagonal pixels are not arranged this way.  The centers of hexagonal pixels are arranged as thus:

[image]

Thus, in order to apply a filter to this, we need to evaluate the appropriate function at these points.  Since the stock filters have been evaluated on a rectangular grid, we cannot use them (although they will produce something that probably looks reasonable).

Fortunately, the transformation is relatively easy.  If we assume the vertical distance between two rows is 1, then the coordinates are *almost* just an `np.arange`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ALTERNATE_ROW_SHIFT = 0+np.sqrt(3)/3 # every other row is "offset" by half a hexagon.  If the sides are len 2/3, the shift is root 3 over 3

def hex_grid(rect_grid):
    rect_grid = np.copy(rect_grid)
    rect_grid[0,:,1::2] += ALTERNATE_ROW_SHIFT
    return rect_grid
```

If you have access to the function that creates your filter, there will usually be some logic that creates a rectangular grid on which the function is subsequently evaluated.  Drop the `hex_grid` function in on the line after to get hexagonally-spaced coordinates instead.

For example, [the wikipedia page on Gabor filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) has a python implementation to create a Gabor filter, shown here:

```
def gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma):
    sigma_x = sigma
    sigma_y = float(sigma) / gamma

    # Bounding box
    nstds = 3 # Number of standard deviation sigma
    xmax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.cos(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.sin(theta)))
    xmax = np.ceil(max(1, xmax))
    ymax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.sin(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.cos(theta)))
    ymax = np.ceil(max(1, ymax))
    xmin = -xmax
    ymin = -ymax

    (y,x) = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ymin, ymax + 1), np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1))

    # Rotation 
    x_theta = x * np.cos(theta) + y * np.sin(theta)
    y_theta = -x * np.sin(theta) + y * np.cos(theta)

    gb = np.exp(-.5 * (x_theta ** 2 / sigma_x ** 2 + y_theta ** 2 / sigma_y ** 2)) * np.cos(2 * np.pi / Lambda * x_theta + psi)
    return gb
```

Note the line involving a `np.meshgrid`.  This creates a rectagular grid with spacing 1 that is used on subsequent lines.  We can simply transform those coordinates to create a new `hex_gabor` function (Note that this is 95% identical to the `gabor_fn` code):

```
def hex_gabor_fn(sigma, theta, Lambda, psi, gamma):
    sigma_x = sigma
    sigma_y = float(sigma) / gamma

    # Bounding box
    nstds = 3 # Number of standard deviation sigma
    xmax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.cos(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.sin(theta)))
    xmax = np.ceil(max(1, xmax))
    ymax = max(abs(nstds * sigma_x * np.sin(theta)), abs(nstds * sigma_y * np.cos(theta)))
    ymax = np.ceil(max(1, ymax))
    xmin = -xmax
    ymin = -ymax

    yx = np.meshgrid(np.arange(ymin, ymax + 1), np.arange(xmin, xmax + 1))
    (y,x) = hex_grid(yx)

    # Rotation 
    x_theta = x * np.cos(theta) + y * np.sin(theta)
    y_theta = -x * np.sin(theta) + y * np.cos(theta)

    gb = np.exp(-.5 * (x_theta ** 2 / sigma_x ** 2 + y_theta ** 2 / sigma_y ** 2)) * np.cos(2 * np.pi / Lambda * x_theta + psi)
    return gb

if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = gabor_fn(4,np.pi/4,4,0,2)
    hg = hex_gabor_fn(4,np.pi/4,4,0,2)
    plt.imshow(g)
    plt.show()
    plt.imshow(hg)
    plt.show()
```

You should be able to drop the resulting kernel into this line `cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)`.

Comment: Wow thank you for the effort sir. I will definitely implement this. Ill be back If I have problems regarding the implementation. Thank youuu!

Comment: hello sir, you said "you should be able to drop the resulting kernel into this line cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)."  you mean to say I call the "hg" variable and replace the g_kernel in that line? am i correct?

Comment: [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d).  The third parameter is "convolution kernel (or rather a correlation kernel), a single-channel floating point matrix; if you want to apply different kernels to different channels, split the image into separate color planes using split() and process them individually." The thing that pops out of `gabor_fn` and `hex_gabor_fn` fits this description.  Note the single-channel caveat.

Comment: I am about to test it on a Hexagonally sampled image.  Ill get back to you after it's done. But do you want to have a copy of my code about square-to-hexagonal pixel conversion? I can send it to you.

Comment: I am not sure if im doing the right thing but I replaced the code from my original gabor_filter implementation in the line "g_kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((21, 21), 8.0, np.pi/4, 10.0, 0.5, 0, ktype=cv2.CV_32F)"  into "g_kernel =hex_gabor_fn(4,np.pi/4,4,0,2)" . I just used "from hex_gabor import * " to import the hex_Gabor_fn that you gave.  Is thid wrong ? I didn't understand what you said about the resulting kernel from this line "You should be able to drop the resulting kernel into this line cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)".

Comment: The code implementation about the conversion is quite too long for me to post it , but it is like 4 different files with 500-600 lines of code but do you think i should post  the code or just give the link to the paper which I got the codes from?

Comment: They do have an implementation. They also posted the rest of the implememtatiom im their University's website nut i can't access it since I dont have the account as a student. But they gave it in their research paper "Hexagonal Imsge Processing" by lee Middleton in 2005.

Comment: So you mean to say What I did about putting the Hex-gabor-fn to the gkernel is right?? ... all my problem now is how can I losd the hexagonal image to the hexgabor function. Since my code implementation doesnt store the converted hexagonal image.

Comment: I already applied the filter to the hexagonally sampled image but it has and error particularly in the line "iltered_img = cv2.filter2D(h, cv2.CV_8UC3, g_kernel)" it says : "TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'". i think it's the type of the new image resulting from the conversion from square to hex?

Comment: Hello sir, I posted a new question and I also posted all the links to my code implementations about hexagonal Image Resampling for more information right here in this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194091/typeerror-expected-cvumat-for-argument-src-applying-filter-on-a-hexagonall"